# Spring data neo4j 3.0.1 properties of type Object not stored anymore

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We are in the process to migrating to neo4j 2 and thus SDN 3.0.1.

We have hit a problem with classes that have properties of type Object. It looks like these are not saved in the database anymore. When I changed one of those properties to String for instance, that particular property was saved.

We are using Object type sometimes because we do not know whether the value will become a String, int, long, or whatever type that is supported in neo4j.

So, is this a bug, or a new restriction, or maybe do I need to register some sort of converter?

Comment: There is no restriction, also no code changed in that area. So very probably a bug. Could you raise a JIRA issue? Actually there are tests for that, so it should work. Weird

Comment: Turns out to be that SDN 3.0.1 is incompatible with Spring 4, created an issues for it: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-458

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be that SDN 3.0.1 is incompatible with Spring 4, I created an issues for it: jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-458